# Storing and requesting information of a server

Tags: html, server

i am kind of a noob in this topic.
What i want to know is how i can store information of a server, lets say i have a simple program on my computer that generates a random number and it stores it on a file named "number.txt", and every five minutes its changing,what i want to send that information to a server and be able to request the current number from a website that i could make.
i have thought of GET and POST but i don't know how to use neither of those.

Sorry if its too specific or for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially GET is used to retrieve data from server, and POST is used to insert/update data to server (for example data from HTML form).

There's basically two way of doing it. You can generate random number on client using JavaScript and send it to server using AJAX. AJAX send POST message containing key and value to some script on server side (most likely some php file).

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { myKey : myRandomValue },
});
```

(In exemple is used jquery library so you have to include it.)

On server side you handle incoming POST request.

```
if (isset($_POST["myKey"])) {
//your number is stored in $_POST["myKey"]
}
```

But JavaScript can't interact with file system so you can't save it to text file. If it is necessary, you can write script in [Perl](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-send-http-get-or-post-request-in-perl.html), [Python](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) or create client-server application written in C++, Java or C#.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, is there a site or something where i can see how to do all this from zero?

Comment: AJAX can be writtren in pure JavaScript but i found it easier do using JQuery. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is documentation with few examples.